# Issue with Spring tag library with spring boot

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot

I can see this question is going to be marked as duplicate, but I can't resolve it using the answers given in related questions.

I am using spring boot and I have a .html file which is using spring tag library.

```
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Welcome, Enter The Employee Details</h3>
        <form:form method="POST"
          action="/spring-mvc-xml/addEmployee" modelAttribute="employee">
             <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td><form:input path="name"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Id</td>
                    <td><form:input path="id"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Contact Number</td>
                    <td><form:input path="contactNumber"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

On the page I am getting error like: unknown tag form:input. Upon loading the page on browser through controller, I can only see the labels and the tag library definition itself!

page in the browser:

[image: page in the browser]

In pom.xml I have the dependency

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

EDIT: The entire pom.xml

```
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>gs-serving-web-content</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Please post your entire POM. Also, you say `.html`, but this is a JSP. If you go with Thymeleaf instead of JSP (my personal recommendation), the extension will be `.html`, but the syntax is slightly different.

Comment: @chrylis: Thanks for replying. Kindly find the edit. Yes, that is a JSP, but I have kept the extension as .html.

Comment: If you are wanting to use JSP, then why are you including Thymeleaf? You make Thymeleaf available and then tell Spring that this is a Thymeleaf file by naming it `.html`.

Comment: 'tell Spring that this is a Thymeleaf file' - even if I don't use Thymeleaf tags in the html, Spring will assume this way ? What would be your suggestion in this case ? Make it .jsp and remove the Thymeleaf dependency from pom?

Comment: I've seen similar problems before, when using the maven shade plugin (which also builds a single fat jar file): the creation of the single files leaves out (or misplaces) configuration files in the META-INF folder that are necessary.  I would suggest you use the "requiresUnpack" option of the spring boot maven plugin, to specify that the taglib dependency must be unpacked - maybe that will preserve that jar file with the proper config files in place...
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html

Comment: Spring doesn't try to guess what the format of the file is to pass it to the correct view engine, it is preconfigured to identify the format via another means (generally by extension) and then pass it to the appropriate handler. By default, `.html` is associated with Thymeleaf (because Thymeleaf templates are HTML). My #1 recommendation is to actually use Thymeleaf, as it's simpler and avoids all sorts of headaches with JSP. Failing that, take out the dependency and rename the file to `.jsp`.

Comment: @chrylis : thanks. I have switched to Thymeleaf now, it is much convenient.